# How to remove make error 77 in my fedora terminal?

Tags: makefile, fedora

I am facing the following output in my fedora terminal which writing make.

```
[shankhaneelbasak@localhost FVCOM_source]$ cd ~/fvcom43-master/FVCOM_source/libs

[shankhaneelbasak@localhost libs]$ make

for item in proj    fproj   julian  metis   netcdf  ; do (./untar.sh $item ) || exit 1; done

cd proj && ./configure CC=mpicc CFLAGS=-O3 CXX=mpicc CXXFLAGS=-O3 F77=mpif90 FFLAGS=-O3 --prefix=/home/shankhaneelbasak/fvcom43-master/FVCOM_source/libs/install

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... mpicc
checking for C compiler default output file name... configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

See `config.log' for more details.
make: *** [makefile:14: all] Error 77
```

Please help me out as I am unable to follow steps to remove it.

Comment: And did you "see `config.log' for more details"?

Comment: Please describe what steps you followed

Comment: @nkrivenko I followed the following steps: Open a terminal.
Set up an MPI environment. On Fedora the mpich environment which can be loaded with module load mpi/mpich-x86_64.
Change directory within which you have downloaded FVCOM and untar the code.
Enter the FVCOM_source directory.
Edit the make.inc file to enable/disable different functionality e.g. wetting/drying to suit your requirements.
Change the TOPDIR variable to the path you are currently in (i.e. the output of the pwd Linux command).
Enter the libs subdirectory.
Type make and wait for the compilation to complete.

Comment: @paxdiablo Can you please tell me how to see config.log details ?

Comment: It will most likely be in the same `proj` directory where you ran `./configure` from. Just open it up with your preferred editor. Unless that editor is `emacs`, in which case you should open it with a *decent* editor, like `vim` :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Here is my configlog details:

Answer (score 0):

Here is my config.log details :

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
```

running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by PROJ.4 Projections configure 4.5.0, which was

generated by GNU Autoconf 2.59.  Invocation command line was

$ ./configure CC=mpicc CFLAGS=-O3 CXX=mpicc CXXFLAGS=-O3 F77=mpif90 FFLAGS=-O3 --prefix=/home/anuga/source/fvcom/FVCOM3.2.2/FVCOM_source/libs/install

### ---------

### Platform.

### ---------

hostname = localhost.localdomain

uname -m = x86_64

uname -r = 5.8.15-301.fc33.x86_64

uname -s = Linux

uname -v = #1 SMP Thu Oct 15 16:58:06 UTC 2020

/usr/bin/uname -p = x86_64

/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64

/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown

/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown

hostinfo               = unknown

/bin/machine           = unknown

/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown

/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /home/shankhaneelbasak/.local/bin

PATH: /home/shankhaneelbasak/bin

PATH: /usr/local/bin

PATH: /usr/local/sbin

PATH: /usr/bin

PATH: /usr/sbin

### -----------

### Core tests.

### -----------

configure:1559: checking for a BSD-compatible install

configure:1614: result: /usr/bin/install -c

configure:1625: checking whether build environment is sane

configure:1668: result: yes

configure:1733: checking for gawk

configure:1749: found /usr/bin/gawk

configure:1759: result: gawk

configure:1769: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)

configure:1789: result: yes

configure:1957: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles

configure:1966: result: no

configure:2030: checking for gcc

configure:2056: result: mpicc

configure:2300: checking for C compiler version

configure:2303: mpicc --version </dev/null >&5

./configure: line 2304: mpicc: command not found

configure:2306: $? = 127

configure:2308: mpicc -v </dev/null >&5

./configure: line 2309: mpicc: command not found

configure:2311: $? = 127

configure:2313: mpicc -V </dev/null >&5

./configure: line 2314: mpicc: command not found

configure:2316: $? = 127

configure:2339: checking for C compiler default output file name

configure:2342: mpicc -O3   conftest.c  >&5

./configure: line 2343: mpicc: command not found

configure:2345: $? = 127

configure: failed program was:

| /* confdefs.h.  */

|

| #define PACKAGE_NAME "PROJ.4 Projections"

| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "proj"

| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "4.5.0"

| #define PACKAGE_STRING "PROJ.4 Projections 4.5.0"

| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "warmerdam@pobox.com"

| #define PACKAGE "proj"

| #define VERSION "4.5.0"

| /* end confdefs.h.  */

|

| int

| main ()

| {

|

|   ;

|   return 0;

| }

configure:2384: error: C compiler cannot create executables

See `config.log' for more details.

### ----------------

### Cache variables.

### ----------------

ac_cv_env_CC_set=set

ac_cv_env_CC_value=mpicc

ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set

ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=-O3

ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=

ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=

ac_cv_env_CPP_set=

ac_cv_env_CPP_value=

ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=

ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=

ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=set

ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=-O3

ac_cv_env_CXX_set=set

ac_cv_env_CXX_value=mpicc

ac_cv_env_F77_set=set

ac_cv_env_F77_value=mpif90

ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_set=set

ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_value=-O3

ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=

ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=

ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=

ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=

ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=

ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=

ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=

ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=

ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'

ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk

ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=mpicc

ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes

### -----------------

### Output variables.

### -----------------

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/shankhaneelbasak/fvcom43-master/FVCOM_source/libs/proj/missing --run aclocal-1.9'

AMDEPBACKSLASH=''

AMDEP_FALSE=''

AMDEP_TRUE=''

AMTAR='${SHELL} /home/shankhaneelbasak/fvcom43-master/FVCOM_source/libs/proj/missing --run tar'

AR=''

AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/shankhaneelbasak/fvcom43-master/FVCOM_source/libs/proj/missing --run autoconf'

AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/shankhaneelbasak/fvcom43-master/FVCOM_source/libs/proj/missing --run autoheader'

AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/shankhaneelbasak/fvcom43-master/FVCOM_source/libs/proj/missing --run automake-1.9'

AWK='gawk'

CC='mpicc'

CCDEPMODE=''

CFLAGS='-O3'

CPP=''

CPPFLAGS=''

CXX='mpicc'

CXXCPP=''

CXXDEPMODE=''

CXXFLAGS='-O3'

CYGPATH_W='echo'

DEFS=''

DEPDIR=''

ECHO='echo'

ECHO_C=''

ECHO_N='-n'

ECHO_T=''

EGREP=''

EXEEXT=''

F77='mpif90'

FFLAGS='-O3'

INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'

INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'

INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'

INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='${SHELL} $(install_sh) -c -s'

JNI_INCLUDE=''

LDFLAGS=''

LIBOBJS=''

LIBS=''

LIBTOOL=''

LN_S=''

LTLIBOBJS=''

MAINT='#'

MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''

MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#'

MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/shankhaneelbasak/fvcom43-master/FVCOM_source/libs/proj/missing --run makeinfo'

OBJEXT=''

PACKAGE='proj'

PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='warmerdam@pobox.com'

PACKAGE_NAME='PROJ.4 Projections'

PACKAGE_STRING='PROJ.4 Projections 4.5.0'

PACKAGE_TARNAME='proj'

PACKAGE_VERSION='4.5.0'

PATH_SEPARATOR=':'

RANLIB=''

SET_MAKE=''

SHELL='/bin/sh'

STRIP=''

VERSION='4.5.0'

ac_ct_AR=''

ac_ct_CC='mpicc'

ac_ct_CXX=''

ac_ct_F77=''

ac_ct_RANLIB=''

ac_ct_STRIP=''

am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''

am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''

am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''

am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''

am__include=''

am__leading_dot='.'

am__quote=''

am__tar='${AMTAR} chof - "$$tardir"'

am__untar='${AMTAR} xf -'

bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'

build=''

build_alias=''

build_cpu=''

build_os=''

build_vendor=''

datadir='${prefix}/share'

exec_prefix='NONE'

host=''

host_alias=''

host_cpu=''

host_os=''

host_vendor=''

includedir='${prefix}/include'

infodir='${prefix}/info'

install_sh='/home/shankhaneelbasak/fvcom43-master/FVCOM_source/libs/proj/install-sh'

libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'

libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'

localstatedir='${prefix}/var'

mandir='${prefix}/man'

mkdir_p='mkdir -p --'

oldincludedir='/usr/include'

prefix='/home/anuga/source/fvcom/FVCOM3.2.2/FVCOM_source/libs/install'

program_transform_name='s,x,x,'

sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'

sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'

sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'

target_alias=''

### -----------

### confdefs.h.

### -----------

#define PACKAGE "proj"

#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "warmerdam@pobox.com"

#define PACKAGE_NAME "PROJ.4 Projections"

#define PACKAGE_STRING "PROJ.4 Projections 4.5.0"

#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "proj"

#define PACKAGE_VERSION "4.5.0"

#define VERSION "4.5.0"

configure: exit 77